# How i can pass value from Controller to View in a Checkbox in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, input, viewbag

Good afternoon I have the following problem, I need to pass the values ​​that brings a CONTROLLER ViewBag a Checkbox in a view.

```
<table>
      <tr>
          <td>
              <label>Select:</label>
          </td>
          <td>
              <select id="type" name="type" multiple="multiple">
                <option id="Custom1" value="Custom1">Custom1</option>
                <option id="Custom2" value="Custom2">Custom2</option>
              </select>
          </td>
      </tr>
</table>
```

Normally in a (Input type="text") i put:

```
<input type="text" name="email" id="email" value="@(ViewBag.Example.EMail)" />
```

but in this case i dont know where put the value, could you help me please? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should do the trick, if the `ViewBag` item is a boolean:

```
<option id="Custom1" value="Custom1" @(ViewBag.SomeBoolean ? "selected" : string.Empty)>Custom1</option>
```

It's worth noting, however, that this is very often more readily accomplished by binding the view to a model and setting that property on the model.  Then you can make use of the HTML helpers, such as `@Html.CheckBoxFor()` and `@Html.CheckBox()`.  The code you're showing indicates that you probably have logic in a controller which belongs in a model.